# How to delete all files (in a directory) whose name starts with certain string?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file, del

I want to delete all files that contain

```
10.
```

And once I specify the directory, I hope it delete all such files in all subfolders of that directory.

I think I need to use something like

```
del <directory path> /s
```

But I don't know what regex I need to use.

Comment: Batch files don't use regular expressions. You can figure out what wildcard pattern you need to use by experimenting using `dir` instead of `del`. Try `dir *10.* /s` to start, and see if it matches the files you want it to match.

Comment: @KenWhite  This worked. It erases all files in subfolers too

Comment: @KenWhite Actually many of these type of trashy-files are read only or something like that. In this case "del /f /s" worked very well.

Comment: The title and the body of your question do not match, so please clarify what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Batch files don't use regular expressions. It supports wildcard patterns, where`*` matches zero or more characters and `?` matches a single character.

You can figure out what wildcard pattern you need to use by experimenting using `dir` instead of `del` (they both support similar syntax). For what you want to do, `dir *10.* /s` should work; see if it matches the files you want it to match, and if not you can adjust it according to your needs.